# Is it possible to provide a default value and destructure that value at the same time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here's what I mean, I want to do something that is a combination of :

```
const {b: {c}} = a;
```

and

```
const {b={c:0}} = a;
```

I know I can break them apart like:

```
const a = {};
const {b={c:0}} = a;
const {c} = b;
console.log(c); //will get 0
```

But is there anyway to do them in a single statement? Something like (below code doesn't work):

```
const a = {};
const{b:{c}={c:0}} = a;
console.log(c); // Hoping to get 0
```

Comment: what is `a`? please provide some examples and wanted results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to get a default `c` value, you could use nested default values and destructuring.

```js
const
    getC = a => {
        const { b: { c = 0 } = {} } = a;
        return c;
    };

console.log(getC({}));
console.log(getC({ b: {} }));
console.log(getC({ b: { c: 42 } }));
```

Comment: Thanks! while this works, I was wondering if there is some native syntax for what I want to achieve, instead of writing a custom function for this specific usecase.

Comment: @Samson It doesn't need to be in a function. `const { b: { c = 0 } = {} } = a;` is the line you're intrested in. Nina's most likely put it in a function to easily show the result of using this line with different `a` values.